# Postgres SQL state: 22P02 - invalid input syntax for integer

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using a sql query to export a database from my company's program.
Everything seems to be fine till I change the date on the "where" statement with a previous one.
Please find below the code:

```
SELECT p."Index", p."PSN" || CAST(p."PNR"as int) AS ID, 
p."PSN" AS Serie, cast(p."PNR"as int) AS Numar, 
pr."PINDate" AS r_gdate, 
CASE WHEN pr."AsigEID"='10' THEN pr."PrimSUM" ELSE 
    pr."PrimSUM"*valuta1."EXCValue" END AS r_prima_lei, 
CASE WHEN pr."AsigEID"='2' 
        THEN pr."PrimSUM"
      ELSE CASE WHEN pr."AsigEID"='10' THEN pr."PrimSUM"/valuta2."EXCValue"
           ELSE pr."PrimSUM"*valuta1."EXCValue"/valuta2."EXCValue"
           END 
    END AS r_prima_eur,
CASE WHEN pr."AsigEID"='10' THEN pr."AsigSUM" ELSE 
    pr."AsigSUM"*valuta1."EXCValue" END as r_sa_lei,
CASE WHEN pr."AsigEID"='2' 
        THEN pr."AsigSUM"
      ELSE CASE WHEN pr."AsigEID"='10' THEN pr."AsigSUM"/valuta2."EXCValue"
           ELSE pr."AsigSUM"*valuta1."EXCValue"/valuta2."EXCValue"
           END 
    END AS r_sa_eur,
pr."AsigStart", pr."AsigEnd", risc."Code", plink."Index"
FROM "PolsRisc" AS pr 
LEFT JOIN "Pols" as p ON p."Index" = pr."PID"
LEFT JOIN "Riscs" as risc ON pr."RID" = risc."Index"
LEFT JOIN "PRLNK" plink ON plink."PTID" = p."PTID" AND plink."RID" = risc."Index"
LEFT JOIN "EXCValues" valuta1 ON valuta1."AtDate" = pr."AsigStart" AND valuta1."EID" = pr."AsigEID"
LEFT JOIN "EXCValues" valuta2 ON valuta2."AtDate" = pr."AsigStart" AND valuta2."EID"='2'
WHERE pr."PINDate" > '2020-08-01' AND pr."IsRezil" = 'false';
```

When I'm using '`2020-08-01`' the query works well. When I try to change it to a previous one eg. '`2010-01-01`' a get an error:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: ""
SQL state: 22P02
```

I was looking for a solution on the previous posts but I didn't manage to solve this issue.

Comment: I think the problem arise due to combined your data and query. Not in the date selection. After you set '2010-01-01' then more data calculating than if you set '2020-08-01'. Something like your column data type is integer and you are using this as string in your query or vice-versa

Comment: just use date function for 2020-08-01 like this date('Y-m-d', strtotime("2020-08-01"))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it is returning `""` or a `null` value into one of the columns you are using integer logic for. The date change is just filtering out the data that would crash it.

You may need to use coalesce to reassign the `nulls` as `0` and then cast it back into being an `int`

```
select
    cast(coalesce(table.column, 0) as int) as result
from table
```

Comment: seems you're right. Now the error comes from the "division by zero". Therefore there was a null or "". I'll try to find a solution to fix it for both cases. your solution brings me the division error.

Comment: i was trying to use NULLIF(column, 0) but it doesn't work

Comment: You could just check if it's zero and only divide if it isn't zero. On a side note, NULLIF and COALESCE if used in this way will do the same thing, they both replace null values with 0

Comment: i found the issue. It comes from the SELECT p."Index", p."PSN" || CAST(p."PNR"as int) AS ID, 
p."PSN" AS Serie, cast(p."PNR"as int) AS Numar,

Comment: Rad news, happy to help

Answer (score 0):

I would advice to read the chapter http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS
. It's a brief and informative read.The cause for the error message is that '' is an empty string that has no representation in a numeric type like integer